# Setting Default "Save as Type" to .kml instead of .php

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, header, kml

This tutorial here is a good source of generating kml from the database using php... http://code.google.com/apis/kml/articles/phpmysqlkml.html

However my problem is that when the script is ran, the file that is generated is saved as .php, not as .kml. How can I make it to be as .kml? Below is the specific code. Thanks!

```
<?php 
$kml = array('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'); 
$kml[] = '<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">'; 
$kml[] = '<Document>'; 
$kml[] = '</Document>'; 
$kml[] = '</kml>'; 
$kmlOutput = join("\n", $kml); 
header('Content-type: application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml'); 
echo $kmlOutput; 
?>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The file you are accessing to generate the file probably has a php extension, thus the browser thinks that is the extension of what you are downloading

Make sure you set in your headers the filename with the extension:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.kml"');
```

Comment: Remember, that if you do not specify this header, your browser will send the current executing script as the filename.

Comment: @BarryChapman thanks brother! sorry i read the other comment first but I gave the check mark to you!

Answer (score 3):

```
header('Content-type: application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml'); 
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="myfilename.kml"');
```